how to fix project fails to connect to database login
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Container_Freight_Station_Management
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\cfsdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    
            txtpassword.PasswordChar = '*';
            txtusername.Focus();
        }
    
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    
        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    
        private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = conn;
    
                // Use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
    
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count++;
                }
    
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
                    this.Hide();
                    Home h = new Home();
                    h.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error occurred: {ex.message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear the textboxes
            txtusername.Text = "";
            txtpassword.Text = "";
    
            // Set the focus to the username textbox
            txtusername.Focus();
        }
    }
}

The code fails to execute the login and brings out the catch message and the database string is correct. How can I fix this please?
I tried to reinstall the MS Access engine but that failed to fix the problem.
I also tried to create a new database access file and successfully connected but still failed to fix this problem
This problem started after I updated Visual Studio.

Show us the actual raw error message.

How do we reproduce your issue?

the error is "Error occured: The'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

@unzaif Do you have 64-bit or 32-bit Office Access installed? Once you find out, you need to change your .csproj build settings so it produces an x64 or x86 executable to match your installed edition of Access.

this worked thanks bro

password is a reserved word in Access SQL, so try using brackets:
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND [password] = @password"


Tested opening recordset with field named password - brackets not needed.
